# How To Find Application User Model ID

Tags: c++, windows

How Can I Find or Set Application User Model ID in My Custom C++ App..
I am using WinToast in C++ and it requires AUID. I read Microsoft official documentation  but it is complicated.. How can i set AUID in my c++ App

I Am Using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: I guess you need to invoke [SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-setcurrentprocessexplicitappusermodelid) and the id is just a string in [CompanyName.ProductName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids?redirectedfrom=MSDN#how-to-form-an-application-defined-appusermodelid) format

Comment: Have your read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/appids#where-to-assign-an-appusermodelid) yet? It is not complicated. You can set a process-wide AUID using `SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID()`, or a per-window AUID using `SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow()` and `IPropertyStore::SetValue()`